# How to get string and Date object from TIMESTAMP in Firebase Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I got timestamp in Firebase Functions with

```
admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

However, when I pass it as a string, it becomes [object object]
I saved it in Firebase Realtime database and when I checked it from console I saw 1505298866520 which I think it is milliseconds since UNIX epoch.
Do you know how can I get string from it or how can I do time calculations with it? Or what type of object TIMESTAMP returns?

Comment: Cloud Functions runs regular JavaScript. So you question boils down to [how to convert a timestamp to a date string in JavaScript](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+convert+a+timestamp+to+a+date+string+in+JavaScript), which seems to lead to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847185/convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-time-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` or `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` hold the following object `{.sv: "timestamp"}`. This is a specific firebase-database object. That tells the server it should use the server's UNIX-time when an object is added to the database.

That is the reason you can not use it as a `date` object in javascript.

If you use `admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP` on the server via `cloud functions` it should represent the same as `new Date().getTime()`